# How to create a serial column in postgres unique to an account

Tags: postgresql

How can I avoid duplicates in a high concurrency environment where I have a multi-tenant table with accountid and receipt number.

I am unable to use SERIAL as a column as I want to have a sequential series of numbers per account.

Comment: Create one sequence per tenant?

Comment: In a single table that is not possible.

Comment: Sure, why not? You cannot use them as a `DEFAULT` value of course, you'd have to choose one of them explicitly (or in a trigger)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have that. If you need sequential numbers, you have to serialize transactions (for example using a lock), so you cannot have concurrency and your performance will suffer. That's the price you have to pay.